# html object to call php and return string

Tags: php, html, object

I want to call a php script (with args) from HTML and to process the returned data
I tried various flavours of :

```
<object id=test1 data="object.php" type="text/plain">
```

where object.php just returns a string, like

```
<?php print "firstText:Hello World";?>
```

I can't work out how to retrieve the returned string. 
I was hoping to find it in something like

`document.getElementById("test1").firstText`
But no joy
Why am I doing this, you ask?
I'd like to get the page working interactively between the user and the server, avoiding the repainting of the browser window that comes with  re-submitting with POST/GET.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses.
I'm not happy using JQuery - another layer beyond my control
I have eventually found the returned text in

```
document.getElementById("test1").contentDocument.body.firstChild.textContent
```

which I can then work with.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$.get('yourpage.php', function(response){
    // response contains the string returned by your PHP page.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

PaulPros idea is probably your best method. Don't forget to include jQuery.

Is there any reason you could not just make the .HTML a .php file and include your script?